# Cannot remove an argument (Point-free style Haskell)

Tags: haskell, functional-programming

I am having a problem with removing an argument 'e' in this function:

```
numocc e = map length . (map . filter . (==)) e
```

The function checks the number of occurences of an element inside a two-dimensional list (lists within list). So you call it as follows:

> numocc 1 [[1, 2], [2, 3, 2, 1, 1], [3]]
>
> *Result : [1,2,0]*

Argument *e* is on the far right on both sides of the equal sign, and is not encased in any parameters. Therefore, I should be able to remove it to get a point-free function:

```
numocc = map length . (map . filter . (==))
```

However I get this error:

> Type error in application
> Expression     : map length . map . filter . (==)
> Term           : map length
> Type           : [[b]] -> [Int]
> Does not match : ([[a]] -> [[a]]) -> [Int]

What is the problem here? Thanks.

Comment: When you test the function numocc on a list it generates an error too. You filter with equal but equal to what ?

Comment: @Zacharie007 
Sorry, I should have clarified, this function counts the number of occurences of the element in the two-dimensional list. So you call it as follows:

 numocc 1 [[1, 2], [2, 3, 2, 1, 1], [3]]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your original function is being parsed as

```
numocc e = (map length) . ((map . filter . (==)) e)
```

So you can't just remove the `e` since it doesn't technically appear at the end of the definition.  However, if you define the operator

```
(.:) :: (c -> d) -> (a -> b -> c) -> (a -> b -> d)
(.:) = (.) . (.)
```

Then you can write it as

```
numocc = map length .: (map . filter . (==))
```

The parentheses on `map . filter . (==)` are required since you can't mix `.` and `.:` due to fixity rules.

However, at this point you're just making this function harder to read and maintain.  It would be better to break it down into smaller sections and introduce some intermediate names, along with adding the right type signature and giving the function a better name to start with:

```
numOccurrences :: Eq a => a -> [a] -> Int
numOccurrences valueToCount values = length (filter (== valueToCount) values)

numOccurrencesInSublists :: Eq a => a -> [[a]] -> [Int]
numOccurrencesInSublists valueToCount = map (numOccurrences valueToCount)
```

This is far more readable, doesn't rely on fancy operators, and expresses your intent more clearly.  Since the case for counting in a single list is a separate function, you can now use it elsewhere too.

Remember, elegant code isn't about making it as short as possible, it's about making it as clear as possible.  Descriptive names (not necessarily long ones), explicit arguments, and small, composable units are best.

Comment: Thank you!
But is there any other way to do this, without introducing new operator?
It makes the function look more confusing.

Comment: @VladyslavBabych Check my edit.  I also made sure to clarify the parsing in the first code block.  Basically, don't try to use lots of fancy operators, requiring the invention of even more operators to effectively use them.  Parentheses are often the simplest and most readable solution, and using explicit arguments is better than pointfree notation in 99% of cases.

Comment: @bheklir 
I am going to accept this answer, however this function is for learning purposes (university), and the task states that I should define it in a point-free style. 
However your comments are still very helpful, thank you! As I can see, it is impossible to make it point-free without introducing a new operator.

Comment: @VladyslavBabych well, it's not impossible, it's just convenient.  [There are several ways to accomplish it](https://blunt.herokuapp.com/?_sm_au_=iVVV63vFDZNMvZLH#input=f%20e%20%3D%20map%20length%20.%20((map%20.%20filter%20.%20(%3D%3D))%20e)), but I wouldn't recommend using any of these in real code